# iframe not resizing along with it's parent window

Tags: html, css, iframe, resize

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5HYve/

```
<div style="position: fixed; top:0; right:0; width:300px; height: 100%; text-align:justify; overflow:hidden;" class="chat-container">
    <iframe id="chat_1" style="width:300px;height:100%;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://www.twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=riotgames&amp;hide_chat=myspace,facebook,twitter&amp;default_chat=jtv"></iframe>
</div>
```

Try and resize the result quadrant, and you'll see that the content within the iframe will not resize based on it's parent's size. I do not have access to the code in the iframe. Is there a way to do this, or am I bound to the poorly written CSS within the iframe?

Comment: You can resize a iframe no problem, but there is no guarantee that the content inside will be "Responsive". if its not then your, a bit stuck

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are using JS to detect available window size. Best I could come up with is refreshing the iframe contents on page resize. Here's a snippet for jQuery that will do that.

```
var 
    iframe = $('#chat_1'),
    url = iframe.attr('src');
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    iframe.attr('src',url);
})
```

You might want to use the debounce plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ to minimize the number of refreshes.

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/TyYj3/5/ here's your example with the snippet.

Comment: This works, but it will also clear the chat of it's contents every time you resize the window. It's not the best solution, but I guess it works.